# How do i find a length of my div_1

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, string-length

How do I get the length of div_1 to show as an alert? 
div_1 is "12345", length should equal "5", but it alerts "13". 
What am I doing wrong?

This is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Exercise</title> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div_1"> 
   12345
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my js:

```
window.onload=function() {

    alert(document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML.length);

    //another way to do it which is longer
    //  var bs=document.getElementById("#div_1");
    // console.log(div_1.innerHTML);
    // alert(div_1.innerHTML.length);

}
```

Comment: You get 13 because there are 13 characters between the tags (counting the spaces and line breaks. Your commented block of code is wrong. You need to remove the `#` in the first line, the variable `div_1` does not exist because you called it `bs`.

Comment: okay, good to know about my commented block of code, thanks. for some reason when I add .length, div_1 still alerts as 13

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML` has a bunch of extra whitespace around it (newlines and spaces).

`<div id="div_1">12345</div>` would probably have length of 5

But you could just trim it first `document.getElementById("div_1").innerHTML.trim().length`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach without the `trim()` overhead:

```
document.getElementById('div_1').childNodes[0].length;
// 5
```